# Make image by docker compose to start automatically Spring Boot and Cassandra

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create docker image by docker-compose. How I can do that?

I can start my project (spring boot + cassandra) by docker-compose up. And everything works great. But in next step I want to make from this project image, push to docker hub and pull it from docker hub to test on other computer. Im tried 'docker-compose build',  'docker-compose push' and then 'docker-compose pull'. After pull I can see information that cassandra and spring-boot-app is downloaded. But then, when I want to run this image by 'docker run' but it runs only springboot, without cassandra.

This is my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  cassandra:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/cassandra/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
    container_name: cassandra

  spring-boot-cassandra:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/springbootsample/Dockerfile
    links:
      - cassandra
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATA_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS: cassandra
    container_name: springboot
    entrypoint: /wait-for-it.sh cassandra:9042 -- java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar app.jar
    depends_on:
      - "cassandra"
    image: myrepo/springbootsample


networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 1):

`docker-compose` is used to handle multiple images. I guess you are thinking it will merge two images into one, which will not happen.

`docker run` is used to run only one image at a time, this was the limitation because of that `docker-compose` was introduced.

`docker-compose up` does `docker run`, `docker network create/add` etc. commands to create you an environment. For use,

`docker-compose build` will build all your images present in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

`docker-compose push` will push all your images to the hub.

`docker-compose pull` will download those images from the hub if present.

and finally, if you want to run those images, use `docker-compose up`. If the images are not present it will download those images first from the hub.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, with docker-compose I need to be in folder which contains docker-compose.yaml?

Comment: yes run `docker-compose` in the folder, or you can pass the file with `-f` option.

Comment: Is it possible to run such an application in a different way? I mean, some of my friend want to run this app (sprin boot with cassandra) on his computer. He need to import whole project and use it with docker-compose?

Comment: give the compose file to him, it will download the images from docker hub and run it.